# jQuery routine working on every other browser except IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

Could anyone please tell me why this following code isn't working in IE10.  This works on all other browsers out there (even IE9), but IE10 doesn't seem to like something about it.  The code is supposed to check for user selection through a drop down list option and activate related fields in the associated form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Company</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">   
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*Hiding the form */
            $(".install_download").css("display", "none");
            $(".hosted_install").css("display", "none");
            $(".reseller_install").css("display", "none");

            function goToByScroll(id){
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'bottom');
            }

                goToByScroll("country");

                $(".subject_category").change(function(){

                    $(".install_Download").css("display", "none");
                    $(".hosted_install").css("display", "none");
                    $(".reseller_install").css("display", "none");

                    switch ($(".subject_category option:selected").text()) {                
                        case "General Enquiry":
                            $(".General_Enquiry").show("fast");
                            break;
                        case "Install/Download":
                            $(".install_download").show("fast");
                            goToByScroll("message");
                            break;
                        case "Hosted Install":
                            $(".hosted_install").show("fast");
                            goToByScroll("message");
                            break;
                        case "Solution Provider - Install":
                            $(".reseller_install").show("fast");
                            goToByScroll("message");
                            break;
                    }
                });
        });     
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 8]> 
        <div style='clear:both; text-align:center; position:relative;'><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>  
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen">   
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual markup?  Hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Could you explain what "doesn't work" means? Are there errors on the page? What's the expected result vs the actual result?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using jQuery 1.6.4 instead of the current release?  The jQuery 1.6 branch came out only three weeks after IE10 was first released in beta, it wouldn't be surprising if there were some incompatibilities.

Comment: The form contains many fields.  This jQuery routine is supposed to show/hide the fields based on user selection through a drop down item located in the same form.  The issue is that IE10 simply ignores this jQuery routine and shows all the form fields irrespective of the user selection.  Whereas this code works 100 percent correctly on all other browsers (chrome, Firefox, safari)

Comment: I will try to upgrade the jQuery library to the latest version once I get back to my desk.

Comment: @Sam Did you ever make it back to your desk?

Comment: @Sam, I added your JavaScript to a JSBin and added the necessary markup to get it to work. It appears to work the same in both Chrome and IE10 (metro & desktop) from what I can tell. Is your markup considerably different? http://jsbin.com/ozoqes/4/edit